# Validate a data type decimal(5.2) in hive with sql

Tags: sql, regex, hive

I am working in validations that validate in final table. I am required to use SQL queries to do this and we are working in Hive.

For example: if I want to validate that a field have NULL values I use this query:

```
select ead 
from apl_loan_tape_ci.tbl_contr_lt 
where tbl_contr_lt.ead is null 
  and data_date_part = "2020-05-31"
```

So, the wrong data (the NULL values) I stored it in another table, with others key fields to be studied later.

My problem is that I have to validate data types like `decimal(5,2)` with a query. I think I have to use regular expressions, but I am not sure how to write a SQL query with regular expressions.

The result of the query must have all that data that doesn't match  `decimal(5,2)`, but that data can be 12.2 for example.

I tried to do this (`CRE_INCM_CRRNCY` is the field with the data):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('/[\d]{5}.[\d]{2}/gm', '') AS Numeric_value 
FROM
    (SELECT CRE_INCM_CRRNCY, KEY_FIELD 
     FROM apl_loan_tape_ci.tbl_garant_lt) a;
```

But it didn't work. Could you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so familiar with Hive but if there is such a construct you are probably looking to use `NOT RLIKE` which will return all the values that do not match your regex.

```
SELECT  CRE_INCM_CRRNCY, KEY_FIELD
FROM    apl_loan_tape_ci.tbl_garant_lt
WHERE   CRE_INCM_CRRNCY NOT RLIKE '[\d]{5}.[\d]{2}'
```

[MatBailie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53341/matbailie) has very kindly pointed out that the [HiveQL docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=27362030#LanguageManualUDF-RelationalOperators) "has an entry for [NOT] LIKE and an entry for RLIKE (Without the [NOT]). So, you may need NOT (string RLIKE pattern)".  If that is the case the above query would instead be written like this

```
SELECT  CRE_INCM_CRRNCY, KEY_FIELD
FROM    apl_loan_tape_ci.tbl_garant_lt
WHERE   NOT (CRE_INCM_CRRNCY RLIKE '[\d]{5}.[\d]{2}')
```

Another way to do this might be to get all the values that match your regex and then use that to get the values that are `NOT IN` that set

```
SELECT  CRE_INCM_CRRNCY, KEY_FIELD
FROM    apl_loan_tape_ci.tbl_garant_lt
WHERE   CRE_INCM_CRRNCY NOT IN (
    SELECT  Distinct CRE_INCM_CRRNCY
    FROM    apl_loan_tape_ci.tbl_garant_lt
    WHERE   CRE_INCM_CRRNCY RLIKE '[\d]{5}.[\d]{2}'
)
```

Comment: The manual has an entry for `[NOT] LIKE` and an entry for `RLIKE` *(Without the [NOT])*. So, you may need `NOT (string RLIKE pattern)` ; [HiveQL Relational Operators](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=27362030#LanguageManualUDF-RelationalOperators)